# leaflet - Calculate a rectangle coordinates from two midline points

Tags: javascript, html, leaflet, coordinates, geojson

I have a `LineString` geometry feature with weight in GeoJSON. Now I want to determine coordinates of 4 vertices of that rectangle. I know how to calculate on plane geometry by using line equation. But on geographic geometry, I'm new. I already read how to calculate one unit of latitude and longitude decimal degree as well as metres per pixel but I'm still confused how to add them to a given point to calculate wanted points. My problem is like this:

Given:

- Broadth of rectangle
- Coordinates of two points making the midline,
  distance between these two points are equal to the width

Result: Coordinates of 4 vertices of rectangle

For example: Two point of `LineString`

```
A (10.767008,106.665884)
B (10.767715,106.667151)
```

Weight of `LineString` is 6 pixels at zoom level 18

I can calculate width of rectangle (distance between these two points), broadth of rectangle (number of metres per pixel, then multiply). How can I use them to calculate 4 vertices' coordinates of this rectangle?

All of my calculated cases are on small scale (part of one street of a city) so I think altitude can be excluded

Comment: You probably mean Width instead of Weight ?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to get the "extent" of your linestring (a.k.a. the "bounding box" of your linestring).  You can use turf.js' turf-extent function to get the extent of your GeoJSON linestring. That extent will be the rectangle you're looking for, as a GeoJSON polygon. You can then use other turf.js functions on that polygon to get the width, length, area, etc